# Proof verification for linear operators

Tags: solution-verification

I gave a proof but it seems rather redundant. What am I doing wrong?

Given $A\in F^{n\times n}$ we define an operator $T_A:F^n \rightarrow F^n$ as such:
$$T_A(v) = A \cdot v$$

Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable, iff $T_A$ is diagonizable.

My proof:

1. If $T_A$ is diagonizable, then there exists a basis $C$ s.t. $[T_A]_C$ is a diagonal matrix. Since $A$ is the representative matrix of $T_A$ in the standard basis, we can infer that 
   $$A=PCP^{-1}$$
   Since A can be represented as $A=PCP^{-1}$, by definition, it is diagonizable.
2. If $A$ is diagonizable, and $A$ is the representative matrix of $T_A$ in the standard basis, by definition $T_A$ is diagonizable as well.

Comment: Just a comment on notation: The notation for the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices with entries in $F$ is $F^{n \times n}$

Comment: Could you clarify your notation? What is M_n(F)? What is F - is it a Hilbert space? etc

Comment: M_n(F) is the set of all n by n matrices over some field F.

Comment: Yes your proof is right since your $T_a$ has the same eigenvalues with same multiplicity as A.